# How to evaluate an expressions with unbound variables in LISP?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a function **multiply** with a variable amount of arguments.

```
(defun mult (&rest args) ...)    ==>    e.g. (multiply a b c)
```

I have a lookup table and each given argument (a, b, c) has an associated number in it. And on the other hand each number has again an associated letter.
Those numbers will be multiplied and the result will be returned.

The problem: 
Trying to evaluate **(multiply 'a 'b 'c)** works perfectly fine.
Trying to evaluate **(multiply a b c)** does not work, because the variables are unbound.
Unfortunately the call is given in the following form: **(multiply a b c)**.

It can also be a nested call: **(multiply a (multiply x y z) c)**

Lookup-table:

```
((a . 1) (x . 4) (y . 6) (z . 2) (c . 3) (res . 144))
```

How can I evaluate something like this?

Comment: I think that you need to show how you define the lookup table and how and where you reference values from there.

Comment: It's simply a list of dotted pairs. In "multiply" each of the arguments are searched in the lookup table. The found values will be multiplied. The result is searched in the lookup table. There you will get the matching alias. The key of the question is, how to make the unbound variables quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.  Longer answer: you can do it differently.

The evaluation rule for function calls is: first all arguments are evaluated, then the function call is evaluated.  The evaluation of the arguments doesn't have any information about what the operator will be.  You can't magically change this basic evaluation rule.

The solution would be to use a macro.  Macros get their arguments as unevaluated forms.

Let's say that you have a function `multiply%` (the `%` is just another character conventionally added to “internal” functions) that works if you call it like `(multiply% 'a 'b 'c)`.  Then you could write a macro `multiply` that quotes each argument form:

```
(defmacro multiply (&rest inputs)
  `(multiply% ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                          `(quote ,arg))
                        inputs)))
```

This means that whenever the compiler encounters a form starting with `multiply`, e. g. `(multiply a b c)`, it will expand it to `(multiply% (quote a) (quote b) (quote c))` before actually compiling it (nitpick: an interpreter would have analogous behaviour).  `(Quote foo)` has a shorter notation `'foo`.